# Evaluating javascript function from swift, getting nil in the completion handler

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview

In my iOS app, i am loading a url in WKWebView, and on a native iOS button click i am calling a javascript function to execute. I am using the following method to execute the function.

```
let result = webView.evaluateJavaScript("saveUserTemplate()", completionHandler: {(response, error) in

            print(response as Any) 
            print(error as Any)

        })
```

Now, the problem is, when the completion handler is fired, i am getting the response and error both as nil.

Please suggest some way to get the response from the java script function.

Comment: where is the javascript function?

Comment: The function is in my server side

Comment: Try removing all code and send hardcoded response from that function to see if things are working as expected at server end.

Comment: @Mr.Bista, Still the response is nil. The value is returning from an ajax function in this method. Is that the problem with the way it is returning from the ajax method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not getting the response from evaluateJavaScript function, because of the ajax call at server side and the javascript function was not waiting for the completion of execution of the ajax call.

The issue is solved using script messages of wkWebview.

I created the configuration for webview and added the contentController in the config.

```
let contentController = WKUserContentController()
contentController.add(self, name: "cardSaved")
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
config.userContentController = contentController

webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 10 , y : 10, width : UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20, height : view.bounds.height - 150), configuration : config)
```

The handler is fired from javascript function, like :

```
webkit.messageHandlers.cardSaved.postMessage("Card Saved Succesfully");
```

Once the event is fired from javascript side, my delegate method is fired:

```
//MARK: - WKScriptMessageHandler Methods

    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage)
    {
        if message.name == "cardSaved" {
            print(message.body)
        }
    }
```